# Progress Bar or BackgroundWorker for my PDF merge application in VB net

Tags: vb.net, pdf, background, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I have this application i wrote and its almost complete.  This part of the application takes every PDF that has a file number and merges all PDF pages that have the same header.  For instance

ZTEST01 Cover Sheet (1)

ZTEST01 Cover Sheet (2)

ZTEST01 Cover Sheet (3)

ZTEST01 Complaint (1)

ZTEST01 Complaint (2)

ZTEST01 Exhibit (1)

ZTEST01 Exhibit (2)

ZTEST01 Military (1)

ZTEST01 Military (2)

ZTEST01 Military (3)

ZTEST01 Summons (1)

ZTEST01 Summons (2)

Turns into:

ZTEST01 Cover Sheet

ZTEST01 Complaint

ZTEST01 Exhibit

ZTEST01 Military

ZTEST01 Summons

From there it takes the file number and merges the pdf's with Cover Sheet and Complaint into:

ZTEST01 Cover-Comp Combined

ZTEST01 Exhibit

ZTEST01 Military

ZTEST01 Summons

After i wrote the application i realized that once all this is done you don't know whether something happened or not unless the user physically checks the output folder where these are supposed to go into to make sure they were actually merged or not.

I tried first using a rich text box to show a list of the PDF's that are being merged, then i moved onto making a progress bar.

This is the following code for the entire thing:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports PdfSharp.Pdf
Imports System.IO.Path
Imports PdfSharp.Pdf.IO
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Deployment
Imports Bytescout.PDFExtractor
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports ExcelDataReader
Imports Microsoft
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports Microsoft.Office.Core
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim folderDlg As New FolderBrowserDialog

        folderDlg.SelectedPath = "G:\Word\Department Folders\Pre-Suit\Drafts-IL\2-IL_AttyReview\"
        folderDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = True
        If (folderDlg.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
            TextBox1.Text = folderDlg.SelectedPath
        Else
            Return
        End If
        Call Xavier()
    End Sub

    Private inputdir As String = Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "unmerged") 

    Public Sub Xavier()
        MergeFiles("Cover Sheet", inputdir)
        MergeFiles("Complaint", inputdir)
        MergeFiles("Exhibit", inputdir)
        MergeFiles("Military", inputdir)
        MergeFiles("Summons", inputdir)
    End Sub

    Public Sub MergeFiles(ByVal name As String, inputdir As String)
        Try
            Dim OutputFile As String
            Dim OutputDir As String = TextBox1.Text
            Dim OutputDocument As PdfDocument



            For Each files As String In Directory.GetFiles(inputdir, "*" & name & "*.pdf")
                OutputFile = "\" & GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files).Substring(0, 7) & " " & name & ".pdf"
                If File.Exists(OutputDir & OutputFile) Then
                    OutputDocument = PdfReader.Open(OutputDir & OutputFile)
                Else
                    OutputDocument = New PdfDocument()
                End If

                Using InputDocument As PdfDocument = PdfReader.Open(files, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import)
                    For Each page As PdfPage In InputDocument.Pages
                        OutputDocument.AddPage(page)
                    Next


                End Using

                OutputDocument.Save(OutputDir & OutputFile)
                OutputDocument.Dispose()

            Next
            For Each files In Directory.GetFiles(inputdir, "*" & name & "*.pdf")
                File.Delete(files)

            Next


            Dim OutputFile2 As String
            Dim OutputDir2 As String = TextBox1.Text
            Dim OutputDocument2 As PdfDocument
            Dim Array = {"Cover Sheet", "Complaint"}
            For Each Ar In Array
                Dim element = Ar

                For Each files As IO.FileInfo In Get_Files(OutputDir2, IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly, "pdf", element)

                    OutputFile2 = "\" & GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files.ToString).Substring(0, 7) & " Cover-Comp Combined" & ".pdf"



                    RichTextBox3.AppendText(String.Format("Merged: {0}", GetFileName(files.Name) & " as " & GetFileName(OutputFile2) & vbNewLine))
                    ' Sets the starting point of the selection         
                    RichTextBox3.SelectionStart = Len(RichTextBox3.Text)
                    ' Scrolls to the caret
                    RichTextBox3.ScrollToCaret()
                    ' Select the range 
                    RichTextBox3.Select()



                    If File.Exists(OutputDir2 & OutputFile2) Then
                        OutputDocument2 = PdfReader.Open(OutputDir2 & OutputFile2)
                    Else
                        OutputDocument2 = New PdfDocument()
                    End If

                    Using InputDocument As PdfDocument = PdfReader.Open(files.ToString, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import)

                        For Each page As PdfPage In InputDocument.Pages

                            OutputDocument2.AddPage(page)

                             For Each fileinput As String In Directory.GetFiles(OutputDir2, "*.pdf")
                            ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
                            ProgressBar1.Maximum = fileinput.Length
                            ProgressBar1.Value = 0
                            ProgressBar1.Visible = True
                            lblPercent.Visible = True
                            Label2.Visible = True
                            Label2.Text = "%"




                            For Each p In fileinput
                            ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Value + 1
                            lbl1.Text = Int(ProgressBar1.Value * 100 / ProgressBar1.Maximum)
                            lbl1.Refresh()

                            Next
                          Next

                        Next
                    End Using

                    OutputDocument2.Save(OutputDir & OutputFile2)
                    OutputDocument2.Dispose()
                    For Each fileinput As String In Directory.GetFiles(OutputDir2, files.Name)
                        File.Delete(fileinput)

                    Next
                    'For i = 1 To Get_Files(OutputDir2, IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly, "pdf", element).Count
                    '    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
                    '    lblPercent.Text = i
                    '    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i)
                    '    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
                    '    lblPercent.Refresh()
                    ' Next
                Next

            Next


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(Err.Number & " " & Err.Source & "-->" & Err.Description, , "Error")
            Return
        End Try

    End Sub


    Private Function Get_Files(ByVal directory As String,
                           ByVal recursive As IO.SearchOption,
                           ByVal ext As String,
                           ByVal with_word_in_filename As String) As List(Of IO.FileInfo)
        Return IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*" & If(ext.StartsWith("*"), ext.Substring(1), ext), recursive) _
                           .Where(Function(o) o.ToLower.Contains(with_word_in_filename.ToLower)) _
        .Select(Function(p) New IO.FileInfo(p)).ToList
    End Function
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to exit?", MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel) = MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit()
            Directory.Delete(inputdir, True)
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form2_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        Dim msgboxresponse As MsgBoxResult
        If e.CloseReason = CloseReason.UserClosing Then
            msgboxresponse = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to exit?",
                                   MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, Me.Text)
            If msgboxresponse = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                e.Cancel = True
                Directory.Delete(inputdir, True)
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit()
                Me.Dispose()
            Else
                Return
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    End Sub

    'Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    '    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    'End Sub

    'Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    '    MsgBox("Success")
    'End Sub
End Class
```

The BackgroundWorker stuff that i tried is the stuff commented out.  The Progress bar i wrote in there *does* work... but the problem is that that its doing a progress per PDF page that is being merged so the progress bar goes from 1 to 100% almost instantly for the amount of PDF pages total that are being merged from that particular directory.   My question is how would i change that for each or put in a for i = 0 to *something*length  So that the progress bar shows when all the pdf's are complete and outputted into the final directory they're supposed to be in?

My approach and thinking was this... this application is merging lets say 20 pdf's from inputdir which is just a folder on the users desktop called "unmerged"

It then merges those pdf's accordingly by File# and their headers and outputs them to folder OutputDir which is "merged" folder.

From there it takes the PDF's with Cover Sheet and Complaint, merges those 2 together and puts them in OutputDir2 which is still the same "merged" folder from above.

i was thinking that i could use the list of files that will be merged from inputdir as an array (20 pdf objects), and use that as the array.length to do a

```
For each PDF in array.length
```

or

```
For PDF = 1 to array.length -1
```

and i couldn't find a way to make the directory of files an array length or count to do this with.

I was thinking that in my code, every time the original PDF's that were used to merge are completed, they get deleted from the original directory (all 20 PDF's in the unmerged folder get deleted).

So from above all the Cover Sheets 1 thru 3 and complaints 1 thru 2, etc... get deleted from their directory with this code:

```
For Each files In Directory.GetFiles(inputdir, "*" & name & "*.pdf")
                File.Delete(files)

            Next
```

And afterward, The original ZTEST01 Cover sheet and ZTEST01 Complaint get deleted once those 2 are merged into "ZTEST01 Cover-Comp Combined" with this code:

```
 For Each fileinput As String In Directory.GetFiles(OutputDir2, files.Name)
                        File.Delete(fileinput)

                    Next
```

Is it a stretch to try to combine

```
Directory.GetFiles(inputdir, "*" & name & "*.pdf")
```

with

```
Directory.GetFiles(OutputDir2, files.Name)
```

as merging 2 arrays; the first being the original 20 PDF objects that were deleted, and then 2 more PDF objects that are deleted once they're merged (ZTEST01 Cover Sheet & ZTEST01 Complaint) and set the combination of both those arrays (22 pdf's or objects) as the .Length of the entire array i want to do a For loop with to give me a progress bar to show the user when the entire application is done?

Also, with the inclusion of the progress bar, is there anyway to throw a msgBox that shows the user that the entire application is complete once everything is done?

I tried putting Call Complete() at the end of all this code in a last sub in the for as

```
Public Sub Complete
MsgBox("Complete")
End Sub
```

But this application calls to that way too early before all the merging is even complete.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question because I haven't read it all. But `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False` is certainly suspicious.

Comment: That's for the backgroundworker that i commented out.  I should have not pasted that in there, sorry.